# Subtotal for hidden rows in Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, subtotal

I have a pivot table, and need to apply different filters. Is there any way I can keep the subtotal values such that it is not changed for every applied filter, so to include hidden rows as well.

For instance I have this table:

[image]

When I apply a filter I get:

[image]

But my desired output is (made manually))):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If you manually hide rows, with no filters you get the desired output.

Let me know if this quick fix is not what you want. For something dynamic and applicable to many rows i would have to revise.

Comment: I have a huge database, and I need to filter for instance top 10 for each category... is there any option or checkbox that would solve the problem?

Comment: There is no native solution. I would create helper columns. For instance, a calculated column that indicates what ID's is top10 within  its respective group.